# WordPress TinyMCE inline styles instead of WP Classes

Tags: wordpress, class, styles, tinymce, inline

I want the WordPress tinyMCE editor to throw inline CSS for elements instead of adding WordPress classes to them.

Like for example if I add an image from media library, the editor will add classes like wp-image, size-medium etc. The style rules for these classes should be applied inline instead of classes.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want such behaviour ? What are you trying to do ?

Comment: I'm guessing for email purposes, as I found this question looking for the same solution, @vard

Comment: @Eddie Considering first that the rules are depending of the css files and can't be known by TinyMCE, and that you need special layout for email (you can't add the css from images like float etc out of the box and expect that it will work in an email) ; if you're planning on using a wysiwyg for building an email content I suggest to provide a limited wysiwyg (with basic bold/italic/underline/text alignment styles) and for more advanced functions provide [custom formats](https://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Styles).